# Nonzero subdeterminants conjecture: has anybody seen this anywhere?

Tags: polynomials, determinant

Let $m\geq2$, $n\geq1$ be natural numbers. Let $M$ be the set of all lists $(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ of natural numbers such that $k_1+\cdots+k_n=m$,
and let $M'$ be the set of all lists $(k'_1,\ldots,k'_n)$ of natural numbers such that $k'_1+\cdots+k'_n=m-1$. For $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where the $x_i$ are formal variables, and for any list $\lambda=(l_1,\ldots,l_n)$ of natural numbers, we write $x^\lambda:=x_1^{l_1}\cdots x_n^{l_n}$. Let
$$
f = \sum_{\mu\in M} c_\mu\, x^\mu~,
$$
where the $c_\mu$, $\mu\in M$, are formal variables. The coefficients of partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{\mu'\in M'}c'_{i,\,\mu'}\,x^{\mu'}~,
\qquad\quad i=1,\,\ldots,\,n~,
$$
are integer multiples of the coefficients of $f$. We form the $n\!\times\!\binom{n+m-2}{m-1}$-matrix
$$
\Gamma = \bigl[\,c'_{i,\,\mu'}\,\big|\,1\leq i\leq n,\,\mu'\in M'\,\bigr]~.
$$
**Conjecture.** The determinant of every $n\!\times\!n$-submatrix of the matrix $\Gamma$ is a *nonzero* polynomial, with integer coefficients, of the formal variables $c_\mu$, $\mu\in M$. Equivalently: for every choice of $n$ columns of the matrix $\Gamma$ there exist integer values for the coefficients $c_\mu$, $\mu\in M$, which make the chosen columns linearly independent (over integers/rational numbers).

Comment: This looks so extremely convoluted and specialized that I think it is going to be very hard many here get into this at all. If this is a research level question, and not something you're just playing with, then you better go to overflow...

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [Nonzero subdeterminants conjecture: has anybody seen this anywhere?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301954)